# Can i with a WIFI antenna capture signals like for exampel a IMSI Catcher?

Tags: c#, signals, wifi, capture

Can I with a WIFI antenna get feedback from everything the antenna recives?

I have the WIFI antenna that follows with the ASUS RAMPAGE EXTREME VI (ASUS 802.11AD 60GHZ)

I want it to be a controlled feedback so I can choose which frequency the feedback is comming from. I want to try to make it to a IMSI Catcher if you know what that is.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with some limitations. Take a look on this: https://www.btframework.com/wifisniffer.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I highly doubt it is possible. Usually modern integrated antennas like the one on your MoBo don't have a monitor mode (meaning they catch packets even if corrupted or not directed to themselves); also, Wi-Fi antennas are highly specialized in their frequency bands, and as far as I know every cellular bands are different from Wi-Fi's in every country of the world.

You'd probably need to buy a different antenna.